# Citations with names instead of numbers

Tags: biblatex, citing

Let's say I have an entry in my bibliography that looks like

```
@book{BOSCH,
    Author = {Bosch and Lutkebohmert and Raynaud},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {N{\'e}ron Models},
    Year = {1990}}
```

When I cite it using `\cite{BOSCH}` I get `[1]` in the PDF.

I would like, instead, to get `[BOSCH]`. Is this possible?

Comment: As a new user you should become familiar with some convention of this site. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can probably get it using the default `debug` style, but I wouldn't recommend that as the real solution. See section 3.3.1 of [the biblatex guide](ftp://bay.uchicago.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for the default styles, and section 4.3 for how to write your own citation styles.

Comment: Do you want to use the last name of the first author or the actual cite key of the item? What exactly do you want your bibliography to look like?

Comment: I would like the cite key of the item to appear instead of the number. Also, in the bibliography I'd like to have "[CITE KEY] - Entry" in place of "[1] - Entry"

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

A shorter solution is to modify the `alphabetic` style. Just force the `label` to be set to `citekey`.

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}
```

And we're done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,westfahl:space}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Initial solution**

You might like this slight modification of the `numeric` style.

We make the `cite` bibmacro just print the `entrykey`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{key}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[key]{entrykey}}}
```

We also have to redefine the bibliography.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield[key]{entrykey}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

I can't help but feel that the label width thing could be improved, but for very long labels that could also go awry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield[key]{entrykey}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{key}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[key]{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,westfahl:space}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]